# reading (not writing) last_write_time gives a file creation error

Tags: c++, file, c++17, std

I'm stumped... it took me a while to track this down.. because I don't have visual C++ IDE installed on the problematic system (it is windows server 2019)... my code works fine with VS 2022 on my laptop (W11 22H2)... anyhow.. I get this exception

> Cannot create a file when that file already exists

I tracked it down to this code:

```cpp
const auto fileTime = fs::last_write_time(p);
```

apparently this function can also write to the file to modify the time.

but I'm just trying to read it... (I didn't add the arguments necessary to write)

does anyone have any idea why this error might be happening?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time

**please note** *it is highly likely that sometimes the file is actually being written to when I call this code (this code is called in a loop, and so is the file that is being written by another program)*

Comment: Just for reference, the error message you quote corresponds to the Windows system error [`ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS), code 183 (`0xB7`). Just a guess: perhaps you have an antivirus that sometimes causes locking of the files it is inspecting (and if the file is frequently written to, maybe that exacerbates the race condition with antivirus).

Comment: ah that could explain it, I do have one running